# attrib -s-r C:\<folder path>/d/s Just wont work?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, file-attributes

I'm trying to change a file within a game I have installed on my computer, but the read only attribute won't change. I've researched this and found a way using the Command Prompt where I can change the attributes of the files; specifically the read only attribute.

The command I was given is:

```
attrib -s-r C:\<folder path>/d/s
```

Thus I opened a Command Prompt and typed in:

```
attrib-r-s<C:/The Creative Assembly>/d/s
```

Each time the result is: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

I've tried copying and pasting the file path, or typing it manually, but it still won't work. I can't seem to work out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to modify ONE file only?  Why not use windows explorer, right-click on file, properties, un-check Read-only checkbox, click OK.

Comment: every time i un-check the read-only checkbox and apply it just checks it again, that was my original problem.
Done some research and this is the solution i found that seemed like it should work, but it just doesn't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are:

- including spaces in the command as outlined below
- not using `< >` in the pathname (`< >` is usually a convention meaning you have to substitute something for `<whatever is included>`)
- are under an admin account or running `cmd.exe` as administrator
- using blackslashes `\` not forward slashes `/` in the pathname

`attrib -r -s C:\The Creative Assembly /d /s`

If that fails, try:

`attrib -r -h -s "C:\The Creative Assembly" /d /s`

Comment: `Creative` and `Assembly` are not valid arguments. ;) Since the path has spaces in it, you need to escape them individually or wrap the whole path with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the exact path where you want to apply this to. You don't want to do it on C:\ and screw up everything.

The command should be something like this:

```
attrib -s -r C:\path\to\your\game /d /s
```

Where:

- */d* - processes folders
- */s* - processes files in all directories

Comment: so even just the next file in?

attrib -s -r C:\The Creative Assembly\Rome - Total War /d /s 

does it need proper spacing and what about the < > round the file path? is that needed?

First time of me using this..

Comment: You don't need <> and use "C:\path\to\your game" if it has space in it

Comment: i'm doing everything the way its meant to be, its working properly and i'm copy and pasting the file path to make sure i don't make a mistake and its telling me that "the system connot find the file specified"

Comment: Can you paste here the exact command you are entering now?