# RStudio on Windows 10 - while saving any type of file, I get "file not found " .Program permissions issue inside \documents\ + subfolders

Tags: windows-10, permissions, rstudio, attributes

I have a weird problem where RStudio can no longer save to any folder other than the parent `<user>` folder (that includes none of its sub-directories, such as `documents` or `document/R` - which are required by the program to function properly.).

I get a "file not found" error.

Here's what I do know and tried:

- I didn't do anything with RStudio prior to the problem starting.
- I tried updating to the latest version - 1.2.1335
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version. Still have this problem
- Permissions-wise - I have Full Control  - every permission as both
  the user and as an administrator and I tried saving various types of
  files when running as both the user and as an administrator.
- the parent folder of `\documents\` , that is the main `<user>` folder is
  the only one that works, and I have the Full.  `C:\` doesn't work because I don't have permission (As the `<user>`).

I also tried the following in PowerShell as admin:

- `attrib -r +s C:\Users\<user>\Documents\ /s /d` - "file not Found"
- `attrib -r +s C:\Users\Ehrlichstein\Documents\R /s /d` "Access Denied" (Also for all subfolders)

I looked for solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/274943/attrib-s-r-c-folder-path-d-s-just-wont-work) and in Windows 10 official discussion, and in RStudio support and couldn't find an answer that worked.

I run Windows Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134 
and R Studio Version 1.2.1335

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

R session info:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.2  htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.2    
 [4] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.0      rmarkdown_1.11 
 [7] knitr_1.21      xfun_0.4        digest_0.6.18  
[10] evaluate_0.13
```

Comment: Have you tried opening R Studio as Administrator? (Right-click the icon and select "Run as Administrator")

Comment: yes, I have tried both

Comment: finally solved it via Controlled Folder Access, which blocked both r and Rstudio. I added 3 exceptions via the "Allowed Apps" setting (open the Start button and search for Allowed Apps or Allow an app through controlled folder access):

    rstudio.exe , C:\program files\Rstudio\bin
    R.exe, C:\program files\R\R-3.6.0\bin
    rsession.exe , C:\program files\Rstudio\bin

Answer (score 2):

finally solved it via Controlled Folder Access, which blocked both r and Rstudio. I added 3 exceptions via the "Allowed Apps" setting (open the Start button and search for Allowed Apps or Allow an app through controlled folder access):

1. rstudio.exe , C:\program files\Rstudio\bin
2. R.exe, C:\program files\R\R-3.6.0\bin
3. rsession.exe , C:\program files\Rstudio\bin

Answer (score 0):

This certainly appears to be a permissions issue. When I have something similar I usually give access to everyone and then remove users/groups to see where it breaks again. Giving access to everyone can be a little heavy handed though, especially if you are not familiar. Here are two options, the first will be lighter and the second heavy.

First, from an elevated CMD prompt, run this:

```
icacls "C:\Users\Ehrlichstein\Documents" /grant Ehrlichstein:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

(Substitute your actual user name if it is different)

Second, the heavier approach, is to grant Everyone access:

```
icacls "C:\Users\Ehrlichstein\Documents" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

If you use this second command you may want to go back and limit access after you ensure everything is running, it just depends on your environment.

The icacls commands used:

- F = Full Control
- CI = Container Inherit - This flag indicates that
  subordinate containers will inherit this ACE
- OI = Object Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate files will inherit the ACE
- /T = Apply recursively to existing files and sub-folders (OI and CI only
  apply to new files and sub-folders)

(Full icacls documentation is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed reply. unfortunately, both give me the C:\Users\Ehrlichstein\Documents: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files" error message (in cmd as  admin). any other suggestions ?

Comment: Access denied messages are caused by not having the rights to complete the action. If this is a managed system you should talk to your IS department, or whoever manages it for you. If this is your own system then you should log into the Administrator account or add your account to the Administrators group. Try this: https://www.howtogeek.com/79890/add-a-user-to-administrator-group/

Comment: thank you. I do not have the local users and groups sub-item under system tools as described.  this also happens when running "compmgmt.msc" as an admin. my user IS an admin, by he way